# How are Zener maximum power ratings derived?

Tags: analog, diodes

Im having trouble to understand how some of the maximum power ratings of Zener regulators are derived, I understand that Zener voltage will be dependant of current Iz, but take this for example: http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/1N5913B-D.PDF

If you look at datasheet, you'll notice that those diodes have a 3 Watt rating, here's what I dont get: look at diode 1N5925B on that same datasheet, its a 10V zener, and Izm is rated a 150mA. The higher the current the higher Vz will be, however with a max current of 150mA in order to achieve the 3W rating, that would mean that Vz would have to be 20V, which is twice the rated Vz of 10V. Vz will drift a bit with a change in current, but it wont drift that much!

According to my calculations a 10V zener with an Izm of 150mA will have a max power rating of around 1.5W so where exactly is the 3W rating coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've sampled a few rows of the table for Zeners of different voltages. It seems to be consistent that the product of the nominal voltage, and the \$I_{ZM}\$ is about 1.5W, half of the 3W.

Now, that 3W figure is something that has to be derated for ambient temperature. So there are conditions at which the maximum dissipation will in fact just be 1.5W.  The derating is 24mW above 75 Celsius, so if the ambient temperature is 137 degrees, it is down to 1.5W.

So, the maximum current values can be regarded as simply being conservative. You can have that much maximum current even if the ambient temperature is quite high. Note that the table does not say anywhere that you must derate \$I_{ZM}\$ for temperature!

It looks like to achieve close to the 3W dissipation, the ambient temperature has to be 75 or less (since the 3W derates above that), and you have to violate \$I_{ZM}\$ (since those values are quoted for 1.5W dissipation).

Comment: Thats odd, take for instance this other diode http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/1N5333B-D.PDF Its a 5W diode, and Izm matches almost perfectly to the Vz max spec. Yet on the 3W diode its completely off.

Comment: So maybe it's just a mistake. It seems to be consistently off. Maybe they intended to calculate the current for 3W, but mistakenly calculated it for 1.5W.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to check that im not going crazy, so tipically speaking Izm would directly relate to Vzm and maximum power rating?

Answer (score 2):

Things are never exactly "just so".  There is always variability in parameters.  In the semiconductor industry 3 sigma or sometimes 6 sigma limits are applied.  Or in earlier days, or with devices that are higher volume, they just simply did a 2X and knew that all devices would fit within this safe operating environment.  It's a fudged number that means if you follow it your design will be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Izm is an operating spec.
Above Izm the electrical result may not be as zenerish as you may wish. But ...

3W is a 'just doesn't quite melt into a pile of molten goo, or walk funny ever after" spec.

See table and notes at bottom left of 1st page.
Note advice[tm]. It says:

- Maximum ratings are those values beyond which device damage can occur.
  Maximum ratings applied to the device are individual stress limit values (not
  normal operating conditions) and are not valid simultaneously. If these limits are
  exceeded, device functional operation is not implied, damage may occur and
  reliability may be affected.

The device is rated at 24 mW/C
so at 3W the rise Tjc = junction to case (or leads) = 3000 mW/24 mW/C
 = 125 degrees C.

This spec is given at a lead temperature of 75 degrees C,
 so junction temperature = 75 + 125 = 200 C.

Junction temperature max = 200 C, so at 3W dissipation and 75 C lead temperature the junction is at its max allowed upper limit.

Comment: Exactly please check the above mentioned data sheet for a 5W diode, http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/1N5333B-D.PDF if you multiply Izm and Vzmax youll get around 5W for every diode. Yet on the other its extremely far off, I wonder if the 3W rating is some kind of technicality or trick...

Comment: @Kaz - It is not obvious that you read or understood my answer. I explain exactly how the 3W figure is arrived at and there is no lying involved. It explains that at a 75C lead temperature (realistically hot) it will dissipate a genuine 3 Watts. Go through what I say slowly and read the parts of the datasheet that I refer to.